# CSS closing the gap margin not working

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I have tried everything to close the gap between "Announcement" and the marquee but no luck.
http://isaac.issharepoint.com/examples/WebPartPages/scrolling.aspx

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really appropriate here (too specific) but: you've floated your marquee to the right, and also set it's width.  If the screen is wide enough that the specified width doesn't reach the left, then it won't reach the left.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too narrow in scope, and doesn't have code included.

Comment: He did provide a link to the live site though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `float:left` to both "Announcement" span and the marquee. Also the marquee has `margin-right:250px`, you will need to remove it to close the gap completely.

Comment: Ok. That seemed to work.  how can I make them even horizontally?

Comment: `width:50%` for both of them should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, first, make them both inline elements, with `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`

OR

You can float them both to the left

> float: left;

Comment: Ok. That seemed to work.  how can I make them even horizontally?